# SSIS common destination, multiple file inputs, different structures

Tags: file, ssis, format, package

I'm sure this question is a common one, but I'm having a real challenging time coming up with a modular design for what should not be an impossible task.  I have a situation where I have common destination tables, about five or six of them, but multiple input files which need to be massaged into a certain format for insertion.  I've been tasked with making the design modular so as we work with new data providers with different formats, the pieces of the package that handle the insertion don't change, nor the error reporting, etc., just the input side.  I've suggested using a common file format which would mean taking the source files and then transforming them and running the rest of the common import process on them.  It was suggested that I consider using tables for this process on the input side.

I guess what strikes me about this process is the fact that the package can be saved as a template and I can use the common pieces over and over and set up new connections as we work with other data providers.  Outside of that, I could see resorting to custom code in a script task to ensure a common format to be inserted into common input tables, but that's as far as I've gotten.

If anyone has ever dealt with a situation as such, I would appreciate design suggestions to accommodate functionality for now and in the future.

Update: I think the layered architectural design that is being emphasized in this particular instance would be as such (which is why I find it confusing):

1. There would be six layers.  They are as follows:

A. File acquisition
B. File Preparation
C. Data Translation to common file format (in XML)
D. Transformation of data to destination format (XML - preparation for insertion into database)
E. Insert into database
F. Post processing (reporting and output of erred out

Since we will be dealing with several different data providers, the steps would be the same for processing the data, but the individual steps themselves may differ between providers, if that makes sense.  Example: We may get data from provider A, but we would receive files from them and they are zipped CSV files.  Provider B's would be in XML, uncompressed.  One provider might send files to us and we may have to go pick files up (This would take place in the file acquisition step above).

1. So my question are:

A.  Is it more important to follow the architectural pattern here or to combine things were possible?  It was a possible suggestion to combine all the connection items in a single package as the top layer, so therefore a single package would handle things like making a service call, SFTP, FTP, and anything else that was needed.  I'm not sure quite how one would do multiple connections for different providers when a schedule is needed.  It just seems to complicate things...I'm thinking connection layer, but have it be specific to the provider, not a be all end all.

B.Same thing with the file preparation layer.

I think a modular design is key, but stacking things into control tasks seems to make things more complicated in design than they should be.  Any feedback or suggestions would be helpful in this area.

Comment: The details are: We have a common destination database which won't be changing.  The input files however are different in structure from one another, but contain data that needs to make it into the same database.  So that being said, I would have to boil the format down to either common file formats to be processed or I would have to take the data and manipulate it to be placed into tables for processing, just to clarify.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would do what was suggested in another comment and import each file into the appropriate temp table first and then union them all later. This will give you more modularity and make adding or removing input files easier and make debugging easier because you can easily see which section failed.  Here is an outline of what I would do:

Step 1 SQL Task:
Create the temp table (repeat as needed for each task with a unique table):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tbl_xxxxxx_temp]') 
AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[tbl_xxxxxx_temp]
GO   

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_xxxxxx_temp](
(columns go here)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Step 2: Data Flow Task
Create a Data Flow Task and import each file into their unique temp table which you created above.

Step 3: Data Flow Task
Create a second DFT and connect each temp table to a union all Data Flow Transformation (convert, or derive columns as needed) and then connect the output to your static data base table.

Step 4: SQL Task: Drop temp tables

```
DROP TABLE tbl_xxxxxx_temp
```

Please note it is necessary to set "DelayValidation" to True in each Data Flow Task in order for this to work.

Comment: There are some other details that were just discussed on Tuesday morning which may complicate the picture more so which leave me more confused about a multilayered reusable approach which is what is being sought after.  When designing an SSIS architecture, I'm under the impression that from job to job, there should be as many reusable components as possible, not one job does everything through  a multitiered package approach or am I wrong?  What is suggested above will work in one situation, but we're handling multiple file types with multiple providers.  I'm sure that changes things a bit.

Comment: IF you have multiple file types and multiple source and (likely) multiple times, there's not going to really by a reusable format.  
If everything is a text file, and those text files in one directory, you could fairly easily input the raw data into one column and save multiple different files into one table structure.  Your table would have 2 columns [FileName] and [RawData] and then do a large amount of SQL magic in a stored procedure and take the needed data and transform it.

Comment: Actually the more I think about it "Yes you can!"

Comment: Lets say you have an Excel file, you can query every column in SSIS, combo them all with a delimiter, union all the excel files and do SQL magic to it and combine w/ the text files above.  

You could find the file type of every file then divert it to a specific sequence container for the file type and input the raw data into one table.  You could even build one package for each file type, and call that package form other packages to maximize usability.  But we would probably need may more details to give a better answer

Comment: I updated the details as to give a more detailed picture of what I was asking before. Any suggestions would be appreciated.